# "Blocked by Play Protect" error when app published on google play

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I published my app on Google Play.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dosote.app

But when we want to install the application with the apk file, we get the Blocked by Play Protect error
I have completed the Play Protect Appeals Submission Form several times, but we still receive this error.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I have completed the Play Protect Appeals Submission Form several times,

Comment: @RyanM I hope this problem has arisen for another programmer to be able to guide

Answer (score 1):

use this form to appeal.

Play Protect Appeals Submission Form
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals

Comment: I registered this form but it was not useful